# multidimensional array to string?

Tags: php, facebook-fql

How would I convert this array from facebook friend list query,

```
Array ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [uid2] => 10000476689*** 
        ) 
        [1] => Array (         
            [uid2] => 10000477429*** 
        ) 
    )
)
```

into a comma separated string, eg: `10000476689***,10000476689***,1000047668***`, so I can insert it into my database. Do I have to convert into an associative array first then `implode(',' , $variable)`?

I have tried this

```
function val_sort($array,$key){
    foreach($array as $k=> $v){
        $b[] =strtolower($v[$key]);
    }   

    //print_r($b);
    asort($b);
    echo '</br>';
    //print_r($b);

    foreach ($b as $k=>$v){
        $c[]=$array[$k];
    }


    return $c;  
}

 $sorted =val_sort($fql_query_obj, 'uid2'); //$fql_query_obj; is from facebook//
 print_r ($sorted);
```

And get this,

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

Comment: You have some viable answers below, but when I see someone trying to insert comma-separated lists into MySQL, 9 times out of 10, it means they should be looking at normalizing the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

Try this assuming your main array is loaded into variable `$array`:

```
$valuesArray = array();
foreach ($array['data'] as $inner$array) {
    $valuesArray[] = current($innerArray);
}

$sqlStringValues = implode(',', $valuesArray);
```

Comment: ha, was just in the middle of typing something almost exactly like that, +1 for speed to you

Comment: Thanks For the reply's Stegrex code did the trick thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$array` is your array of data.

```
$array = array_map(function($data) { return $data['uid2']; }, $array);
$string = implode(',', $array);
```